# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on remote but works fine on localhost

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string

i have react with asp.net core website . it worked fine on localhost but when published on iis remote server the timeout error occurs.
the front-end (react client) and back-end(server)  asp.netcore webapi work independently.

before uploading i changed the following in program.cs in webapi.

`usUrl("https://localhost:4000")`
to `useUrl("https://www.virtualcollege.pk:4000")`
i also changed the front-end baseurl similarly.

moreover, the connectionstrings in appsettings.json is correct for both databases.
i added migration and updated the databases successfully.
the website is live but timeout error occur :
[virtualcollege.pk](https://www.virtualcollege.pk/)

i also tried the url with "https://myip-address:4000"
thanks in advance for help.
if i remove port number from url and publish on local folder than upload to remote server . the webapi.exe on local machine runs as follows:
[image: webApi on local here]

Comment: You have to open 4000 port in incoming rule in firewall.

Comment: hi @Alex how i have access to firewall on remote hosting server? can i  remove the port 4000 from url like 'https ://www.virtualcollege.pk/api/courses'

Comment: hi @Alex i have remove port number from url now the error is : `GET https://www.virtualcollege.pk/api/courses/ 404 `    creating new user have same error `POST https://www.virtualcollege.pk/users/register 404`

Answer (score 1):

You have to open incoming request for 4000 port. Try some methods below.

> **Windows Server**

[Please check this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15) or [this one](https://www.parallels.com/blogs/ras/configuring-windows-server-firewall-for-parallels-ras/)

> **Ubuntu/Debian**

```
sudo ufw allow 4000/tcp
sudo ufw status // check status
```

> **CentOS**

First, you should disable selinux, edit file /etc/sysconfig/selinux so it looks like this:

```
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Save file and restart system.

Then you can add the new rule to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
```

and restart iptables with `/etc/init.d/iptables restart`

Comment: hie @Alex i asked the hosting provider for opening 3000 and 4000 port for incoming rules in firewall . they have open these ports .but the same error on remote but works fine on local machine with url localhost. thanks and regards